# Unicode Power Symbols in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, unicode, .net-4.6

As announced on this [site](https://unicodepowersymbol.com/) there are new Power symbols in Unicode 9.0 available and I tried to include one symbol to my XAML code

e.g. `<Button Content="&#x23FB;" />`

but it will not recognized correctly! (it's always an rectangle)
So I think I have to update Unicode somehow? Any suggestions?!

Comment: Few (if any) fonts have *all* Unicode characters. Which font did you use?

Comment: "Update Unicode": Nope, Unicode is pretty much a fixed concept. But it does have an extensible set of characters. Copy and past the "rectangle" (which would be really difficult from a Button, so try it with something else). It's still a U+23FB codepoint. So, as the answer says, it's a font issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a font that contains the glyph for the desired character, e.g. [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).